# Respuesta no desencadena ningún evento de Ajax

Tags: php, ajax, postgresql

Vengo con esta duda, que he visto a sido consultada muchas veces, pero en ninguno de los temas que vi pude encontrar una solución.

Mi problema es, que estoy tratando de recuperar información de mi BD PostgreSQL para mostrarla, pero el llamado de Ajax dispara el evento de "error" donde se indica el error del titulo.

Este es el procedimiento del llamado:

funcion.JS

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'data/ajax.php',
    dataType: 'json',
    data: {action: 'cargar', 
           usu_id: usu_id},
    type: 'get',
    sucess: function(data){
      console.log(data);
      $('#load_contnent').show();
      alert('Formularios cargados correctamente.');
    },
    error: function (data, jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
      console.log(data);
      alert('Error: ' + jqXHR + ', ' + textStatus.message);
    },
    done: function(results) {
      console.log(data);
      alert('Entro en done.');
    },
    fail: function( jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown ) {
      console.log( 'Could not get posts, server response: ' + textStatus + ': ' + errorThrown );
    }
});
```

ajax.PHP

```
$action = $_GET['action'];
switch($action) {
    case 'cargar' : 
        $formulario = new Panel();
        $formulario->CargarFormulario($_GET['usu_id']);
        break;
}
```

funcion.PHP

```
public function CargarFormulario($usu_id){
    require_once "param_panel.php";
    $Datos = new ParametrosPanel();
    $resultado = $Datos->CargarTodo($usu_id);

    $arr = array('formulario' => $resultado);
    echo json_encode($arr);
    exit;
}
```

------ EDIT-----

Gracias a la sugerencia de Max Sandoval, pude ver en mi código que tenia una función **vardump()** sin propósito en la función con el llamado SQL, y al eliminar esa función ya no se produce el error original por el que hice la consulta en un comienzo, ahora simplemente, se ejecuta el llamado, pero la respuesta no desencadena ningún evento especificado en AJAX.

Agrego la función con la consulta sql:

CargarTodo.PHP

```
$sql = "select *
            from construccion
            where usu_id=$usu_id";
    $result = pg_query($this->con->conectar(), $sql);
    pg_close($this->con->conectar());
    if($result!=null){
        return pg_fetch_all($result);
    }else{
        echo false;
    }
```

También dejo evidencia de lo que se observa en la consola de Network del navegador.

------ EDIT --------

Al revisar la consola, la respuesta de ajax llega de esta forma:

```
{"formulario":{"0":{"cons_id":"1","usu_id":"1","cons_nombre":"asdqwed","cons_titulo":"asdqwed","cons_contenido":"<label class=\"arrastrable ui-draggable ui-draggable-handle\" id=\"c_1\" style=\"position: relative;\">Ejemplo de etiqueta.<\/label><br><input class=\"arrastrable ui-draggable ui-draggable-handle\" type=\"text\" value=\"Ejemplo de input\" id=\"c_11\" style=\"position: relative;\"><br>"},"1":{"cons_id":"2","usu_id":"1","cons_nombre":"test","cons_titulo":"test","cons_contenido":"<p class=\"arrastrable ui-draggable ui-draggable-handle\" id=\"c_1\" style=\"position: relative;\">Ejemplo de un parrafo.<\/p><br>"},"2":{"cons_id":"3","usu_id":"1","cons_nombre":"test2","cons_titulo":"test2","cons_contenido":"<p class=\"arrastrable ui-draggable ui-draggable-handle\" id=\"c_1\" style=\"position: relative;\">Ejemplo de un parrafo.<\/p><br><input class=\"arrastrable ui-draggable ui-draggable-handle\" type=\"text\" value=\"Ejemplo de input\" id=\"c_11\" style=\"position: relative;\"><br><label class=\"arrastrable ui-draggable ui-draggable-handle\" id=\"c_111\" style=\"position: relative;\">Ejemplo de etiqueta.<\/label><br>"},"3":{"cons_id":"4","usu_id":"1","cons_nombre":"qweqwe","cons_titulo":"qweqwe","cons_contenido":"<p class=\"arrastrable ui-draggable ui-draggable-handle\" id=\"c_1\" style=\"position: relative;\">Ejemplo de un parrafo.<\/p><br><input class=\"arrastrable ui-draggable ui-draggable-handle\" type=\"text\" value=\"Ejemplo de input\" id=\"c_11\" style=\"position: relative;\"><br>"},"4":{"cons_id":"5","usu_id":"1","cons_nombre":"test3","cons_titulo":"test3","cons_contenido":"<input class=\"arrastrable ui-draggable ui-draggable-handle\" type=\"text\" value=\"Ejemplo de input\" id=\"c_1\" style=\"position: relative;\"><br><p class=\"arrastrable ui-draggable ui-draggable-handle\" id=\"c_11\" style=\"position: relative;\">Ejemplo de un parrafo.<\/p><br>"},"5":{"cons_id":"6","usu_id":"1","cons_nombre":"test4","cons_titulo":"test4","cons_contenido":"<div class=\"arrastrable interno ui-draggable ui-draggable-handle ui-droppable\" id=\"e_1\" style=\"border: 0.5px dotted black; height: 50%; width: 90%; min-height: 1px; min-width: 1px; position: relative; background: rgb(106, 192, 193);\"><\/div><br><label class=\"arrastrable ui-draggable ui-draggable-handle\" id=\"c_11\" style=\"position: relative;\">Ejemplo de etiqueta.<\/label><br>"},"6":{"cons_id":"7","usu_id":"1","cons_nombre":"ertgher","cons_titulo":"ertgher","cons_contenido":"<label class=\"arrastrable ui-draggable ui-draggable-handle\" id=\"c_1\" style=\"position: relative;\">Ejemplo de etiqueta.<\/label><br>"},"7":{"cons_id":"8","usu_id":"1","cons_nombre":"ertert","cons_titulo":"ertert","cons_contenido":"<label class=\"arrastrable ui-draggable ui-draggable-handle\" id=\"c_1\" style=\"position: relative;\">Ejemplo de etiqueta.<\/label><br><form class=\"arrastrable interno ui-draggable ui-draggable-handle ui-droppable\" id=\"e_11\" style=\"border: 0.5px dotted black; height: 50%; width: 90%; min-height: 1px; min-width: 1px; position: relative;\"><\/form><br>"},"8":{"cons_id":"9","usu_id":"1","cons_nombre":"asdqw","cons_titulo":"asdqw","cons_contenido":"<p class=\"arrastrable ui-draggable ui-draggable-handle\" id=\"c_1\" style=\"position: relative;\">Ejemplo de un parrafo.<\/p><br>"},"9":{"cons_id":"10","usu_id":"1","cons_nombre":"Prueba_0611","cons_titulo":"Prueba_0611","cons_contenido":"<br><div class=\"interno ui-droppable ui-sortable\" id=\"e_2\" style=\"border: 0.5px dotted black; height: 50%; width: 90%; min-height: 1px; min-width: 1px; background: white;\"><form class=\"interno ui-droppable ui-sortable ui-sortable-handle\" id=\"e_3\" style=\"border: 0.5px dotted black; height: 50%; width: 90%; min-height: 1px; min-width: 1px; background: white;\"><input class=\"arrastrable ui-draggable ui-draggable-handle ui-droppable ui-sortable-handle\" type=\"text\" value=\"Ejemplo de input\" id=\"c_5\" style=\"position: relative;\"><br class=\"ui-sortable-handle\"><\/form><br class=\"ui-sortable-handle\"><label class=\"arrastrable ui-draggable ui-draggable-handle ui-droppable ui-sortable-handle\" id=\"c_6\" style=\"position: relative;\">Ejemplo de etiqueta.<\/label><br class=\"ui-sortable-handle\"><\/div><br><div class=\"interno ui-droppable ui-sortable\" id=\"e_4\" style=\"border: 0.5px dotted black; height: 50%; width: 90%; min-height: 1px; min-width: 1px; background: white;\"><p class=\"arrastrable ui-draggable ui-draggable-handle ui-droppable insidePopup ui-sortable-handle\" id=\"c_1\" style=\"position: relative;\">Ejemplo de un parrafo.<\/p><\/div><br>"},"10":{"cons_id":"11","usu_id":"1","cons_nombre":"","cons_titulo":"","cons_contenido":""},"11":{"cons_id":"12","usu_id":"1","cons_nombre":"","cons_titulo":"","cons_contenido":""}}}
```

Y en la pestaña "Preview" se ve así:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Muestra el  código de `cargarTodo()`

Comment: Ahí agregue la función, pero también cambio la problemática que tenia. Saludos.

Comment: Te refieres a que `$('#load_contnent').show();` no lo ejecuta? te has dado cuenta como está escrito `cotnent`? así está en el id de tu html?

Comment: Jaja no me había fijado en ese error ortográfico, pero si, el id corresponde al de hrml xD

Answer (score 0):

Creo que tu problema está en que funcion.php debe retornar el array y el ajax.php debe hacer el echo de json_encode

Prueba esto:
ajax.php

```
$action = $_GET['action'];
switch($action) {
    case 'cargar' : 
        $formulario = new Panel();
        echo json_encode($formulario->CargarFormulario($_GET['usu_id']));
        break;
}
```

funcion.php

```
public function CargarFormulario($usu_id){
    require_once "param_panel.php";
    $Datos = new ParametrosPanel();
    $resultado = $Datos->CargarTodo($usu_id);

    $arr = array('formulario' => $resultado);
    return $arr;
}
```

Comment: Gracias por responder, pero ya había probado esa alternativa, de igual manera llega al error de ajax la respuesta.

Comment: Pregunta, si inspeccionas en Network la respuesta de ajax.php es realmente un json lo que está retornando?
Podrías mandar lo que te retorna?
Podría ser que el array no está bien construido

Comment: Ahí agregue más información con lo que se ve en el Network de la consola. Saludos.

Comment: Ah ok! me parece que el problema puede ser porque estás pasando el resultado de la query ($resultado) directo al array. Haz lo siguiente: $arr = pg_fetch_all($resultado)

Comment: Gracias por tu comentario Max, pero ya tengo implementada la función pg_fetch_all(), edite nuevamente la consulta para agregar la función sql y como se retorna el resultado.

Comment: Genial, que bueno que lo has podido pillar.
Exito en tu proyecto!